# Hardcoding values into ndb model

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I am working in webapp2 framework using python, I have a parent class(Examplestart) which has three properties:

```
variable = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=DBUser)
time = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
statement = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

The Example has two children class(Example1 & Example2) , I want to hardcode properties in Examplestart such that:

```
my_example = DBExamplestart(
   variable = '776',
   statement = ['First']
)
my_example.put()
```

Where should I insert this code in my file ? If I use it inside Examplestart the code isn't working. my_example is related to class Example1.

Comment: What? If you want to create an entity in the datastore, just do it. Once you've done that you don't need to create it again, it'll already exist.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman:The entity is already there, I just want to test the entity by giving values. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default value in you child entity:

```
class DBExamplestart(Examplestart):
    variable = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=DBUser, default=ndb.Key(DBUser, 776))
    statement = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, default='First')
```

If you have more complex things to do (such as retrieving a particular id, instead of 776), you can look into [Model Hooks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks).
For example, _pre_put_hook() will allow you to do anything on your entity before you persist it.